# I cant update useState more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

My components shows video on page and two buttons on bottomm of clip with two states for each button.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Clip from '../../../video/clip.mp4'

const BannerBigVideo = () => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
    const [isMute, setIsMute] = useState(true);
    return(
        <>    
        <video id="BannerVideo" loop muted autoPlay>
            <source src={Clip} type="video/mp4" /> 
        </video>
        <button id="MuteButton">{isMute ? "Volume" : "Mute"}</button>
        <button id="PlayButton">{isPlaying ? "Stop" : "Start"}</button>
        <>
    )
```

I wrote handler for video mute, working correctly:

```
    const changeMuteHandler = () => {    
        var video = document.getElementById("BannerVideo");
        video.muted = !video.muted;
        setIsMute(video.muted);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        var muteButton = document.getElementById("MuteButton");
        muteButton.addEventListener("click", changeMuteHandler);
        return () => muteButton.removeEventListener("click", changeMuteHandler);
    },[])
```

But handler for play/stop function won't work. I wrote it just very simply:

```
    const changePlayHandler = () => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
    useEffect(()=>{
        var playButton = document.getElementById("PlayButton");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", changePlayHandler);
        return () => playButton.removeEventListener("click", changePlayHandler);
    },[])
```

I only want to achive ***isPlaying*** state change.
It only changing very first time and wont change anymore.

What can change in my code to get that button work correctly? *(mean change state every click event)*

Comment: `var video = document.getElementById("BannerVideo");` you should not access the dom directly when using react. Appending click-handlers works like `<button onClick={changeMuteHandler} id="MuteButton">`

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.getElementById()` with React code -- for one, in your case that means you can only ever have one video on a page.